# When export to csv, the columns is inclined to the right

Tags: crystal-reports-2008

I have a report when priting to csv, its coulmn is inclined to the right although I design the column data align with the columns.

Could you kindly guide me how to resolve it?
Thank you very much

Comment: Please post an example of the problem you're having. Note that CSV files don't contain any alignment information.

Comment: I think it replates to the data.
Because I divide my data into 2 tables and when showing by CSV, the space that the first table equal with the space that showed the second table

Comment: Here is the link for CSV when using Microsoft Excel to view it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qgbf1gycm8qy6tq/Untitled.png